# weird JFrame problems

Tags: jframe

I am trying to get a box to move in a JFrame by repainting it, but for some reason i cannot figure out it will not work. I know its probably something really stupid but here are my classes: (also sorry for the formatting its a pain in the ass...)  It gives me an error on the frame.add(square) line.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Runner extends JFrame{

final static int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;
final static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
final static int BOX_WIDTH = 50;
final static int BOX_HEIGHT = 50;

public static void main (String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setTitle("Animation");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Component square = new Component();
    Dimensions.setBoxDimensions(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);

    frame.add(square);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        Dimensions.setPosition(i,i);
        square.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
}



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Component extends JFrame{

public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fillRect(Dimensions.xPos, Dimensions.yPos, Dimensions.boxWidth,            Dimensions.boxHeight);
}
}





public class Dimensions {

public static int boxHeight = 50;
public static int boxWidth = 50;
public static int xPos = 0;
public static int yPos = 0;

public static void setBoxDimensions(int width, int height){
    boxHeight = height;
    boxWidth = width;
}
public static void setPosition(int x, int y){
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your component class is a JFrame you cannot add teh JFrame to a JFrame. You may want to add a JPanel to the JFrame and paint on the JPanel instead.

Or you may be intending to extend java.awt.Component instead?

```
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 public class MyComponent extends JPanel{

     public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
           g2.fillRect(Dimensions.xPos, Dimensions.yPos, Dimensions.boxWidth,                          Dimensions.boxHeight);
  }
  }
```

And when you want a Component you can do this:

```
  JPanel square = new MyComponent();
```

Comment: so JPanel panel = new JPanel();
and then panel.add(square);??

Comment: I added some examples to help.

Comment: Naming your own class Component may cause some problems since there is a java.awt.Component, even though it can be done. So I renamed it MyComponent for convenience.

Comment: when i extend Component instead of JFrame it gets rid of the run time error on the frame.add(square); line. I get nothing displayed though :(. and i renamed mine too. i didnt know there was the java.awt.Component thing.. i dont know anything about it so is there anything else i have to change?

Comment: Try it without the for loop first and see if the basic shape is drawn, then try the animation.

Comment: i am currently trying that. i changed My Component simply to g.drawRect(5,5,100,100) and the runner down to bare bones too. for some reason it does not want to display. this is baffling to me.

Comment: Try extending JPanel instead since that has a paintComponent method to override.

Comment: this is my main method
---------------------
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
  frame.setTitle("Animation");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true); 
  
  MyComponent a = new MyComponent();
  
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  
  frame.add(panel);
  panel.add(a);

--------------------------------
this is the MyComponent 
public class MyComponent extends JPanel{

 public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
  g.drawRect(10,10,100,100);
 }
}
this results in a JFrame with nothing in it, what am i doin wrong

Comment: I have also tried changing it to extend JFrame and Component and neither work. im about to give up on this it makes no sense.

Comment: When you create the instance of MyComponent then you add that to the frame. frame.add(a);

Comment: i figured out the problem and it should extend JComponent, not JFrame.. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

It's better to override the "paint" method in your JFrame. It's much easier to do.

```
@override 
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super();
    /*
      put the code to draw your shape of shapes here
    */
}
```

You can call repaint method of your JFrame whenever you want to update your JFrame.